# Complex integrate and residues

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

Evaluate the integral of that $f(z)=\frac{z+1}{z^2-2z}$ around the circle $|z|=3$ oriented counterclockwise

First I found that singularity points are $z=0,z=2$
$$\star\int_{|z|=3}\frac{z+1}{z^2-2z}=2\pi i *Res_{z=0}f(z)+2\pi i*Res_{z=2}f(z) $$
Then I use partial fractions $\frac{z+1}{z^2-2z}=\frac{-1}{2z}+\frac{3}{2(z-2)}$
$$Res_{z=0}f(z)=Res_{z=0}\frac{-1}{2z}+Res_{z=0}\frac{3}{2(z-2)}=-\frac{1}{2}$$
$$Res_{z=2}f(z)=Res_{z=2}\frac{-1}{2z}+Res_{z=2}\frac{3}{2(z-2)}=\frac{3}{2}$$
$$\star\space2\pi i *Res_{z=0}f(z)+2\pi i*Res_{z=2}f(z)=2\pi i (-\frac{1}{2})+2\pi i \frac{3}{2}=2\pi i$$

1)That is right?

2)I can always do what I did in $\star$ when the singularity points are within the region or on the boundary?

3)When I need to expand the function in series to find the residues?

Comment: Assuming the decomposition is correct, it looks fine. If you don't decompose, I am not sure how you would be able to find the poles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary to expand in partial fractions.

The residue at $z=0$ is simply

$$\lim_{z\to 0}zf(z)=-\frac12$$

While the residue at $z=2$ is given by

$$\lim_{z\to 2}(z-2)f(z)=\frac32.$$

Thus, the value of the integral is $2\pi i$.

Comment: Oh, so *that's* what the OP was asking. Actually I just noticed I didn't even looked at the function at all!

Comment: You can answer my questions 2) and 3)?